# Is passing function name literals to higher order functions safe?

Tags: php, higher-order-functions

In Javascript I am used to pass functions around, since they are first class values. However, in PHP I get the notice "*Use of undefined constant add - assumed 'add'*":

```
function fold($f, $acc) {
  return function ($xs) use ($f, &$acc) {
    return array_reduce($xs, $f, $acc);
  };
}

function add($m, $n) {return $m + $n;};

fold(add, 0) ([1, 2, 3]);
```

I know I can just assign a lambda `$add = function ($m, $n) {return $m + $n;}`, I prefer the more concise `add` though. Is this safe or am I doomed in the long run?

Comment: Function name should be in quotes: `fold('add')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP functions aren't quite as "first-class" as that. You're not actually passing the function by name there, you're just passing an undefined constant, `and`. The behaviour in that situation is to raise a notice*, and fall back to the string value "and"; this is a valid identifier for your global function, and so the code runs successfully (albeit with an error notice).

The only way to pass the function directly into `fold()` is to assign it to a variable, as you say. Otherwise, you're simply passing the name of a global function, and while that will work fine, it probably isn't quite what you're looking to achieve.

*Just a quick addendum to note that this notice will change to a warning in PHP 7.2

Comment: My generic functions are usually global. So it is probably safe in most cases. On second thought, when I assign a partially applied function (e.g. `$sum = fold(add, 0)`) I wind up with `$` anyway. So I better get accustomed to this syntax.